# How to convert Dount chart to Pie chart by using Morris

Tags: javascript, php, html, morris.js

I have created Dount Chart by using Morris.js,code is below check once.

```
//html code
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Live Donut Chart by using Morris.js with Ajax PHP</title>  
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" />  
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:900px;">
   <h2 align="center">Live Donut Chart by using Morris.js with Ajax PHP</h2>   
   <div id="chart"></div>
       <div id="morrisdetails-item" class="morris-hover morris-default-style" style="position:static;
    float: left;
            ">
            <div class="morris-hover-row-label">2010 Q4</div>
            <div class="morris-hover-point">this is a test</div>
        </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>


//js code 
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
 var donut_chart = Morris.Donut({   
     element: 'chart',
     data:[{"label":"Laravel","value":"10"},{"label":"Symfony","value":"5"},{"label":"Yii","value":"8"},{"label":"CakePHP","value":"6"},{"label":"Codeigniter","value":"18"}]
    });
    for(i = 0; i < donut_chart.segments.length; i++) {
        donut_chart.segments[i].handlers['hover'].push( function(i){
            $('#morrisdetails-item .morris-hover-row-label').text(donut_chart.data[i].label);
            $('#morrisdetails-item .morris-hover-point').text(donut_chart.data[i].value);
        });
    }
  }); 

</script>
```

The above code is working fine,this is Dount chart how can I convert as `Pie` chart.

I tried like `type:Pie` but it is not working, could any one help on this one ?

Thanks

Comment: as i see there is no pie chart in  [morris.js](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/)

Comment: @moufed ,https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html check this link ,there is pie chart but how can we get i am not understanding .

Comment: "chrart.js" it's different library    
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html
checkout  this [example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html) to know how to use chart js

Comment: This require a lot of work, you can try my fork, there is one option for this https://pierresh.github.io/morris.js/